# Call a function in another funtion

Tags: javascript, function

I want to get the first name of a customer and use that in other functions.

I have an address:

John Doe
Streetname 1
1234AA Village

```js
function firstName(){
        let address = "John Doe\nStreetname 1\n 1234AA Village";
        let firstname = adres.split(' ')[0]; 
    }

function customerText(){
   firstName();
   let text = "Dear "+firstname+", how is life?";
   alert(text);
}
```

So that the result would be: Dear John, how is life?

But unfortunately, it doesn't. Don't know how this should work?

Comment: `firstname` is scoped to `firstName()` when you use `let`, so `customerText()` cant' see it. You could use a global scope, or return `firstname` from `firstName()`  and then set `firstname = firstName()` in `customerText()`.

Comment: Also `adres.split(' ')[0];` should be `address.split(' ')[0];`. Also also, first names can have spaces. `Mary Beth Doe`, for example; first name is "Mary Beth", not "Mary". Splitting on `' '` is fine for learning code, but for anything legal, this should not be used to determine first/surname, etc.

Comment: You need to declare firstname in a scope that is available to customerText(), in your example, the variable firstname, is only available to the function scope of firstname(). Alternatively, and  in my opinion more elegantly, you could let firstName() return a string and then assign the result of the function call.

Comment: Sorry sorry sorry, I see some translations typos indeed (adres -> address)

Comment: @TimLewis You are totally right about that it is not perfect (missing the second name), but for my purpose it will do at the moment.

Comment: Yeah, like I said, for testing code and understanding functions like split, etc., there is nothing wrong with your code. I only bring it up as my wife receives so many documents where her name is incomplete due to similar approaches. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

return the firstname and use it in the second function

```js
function firstName(){
  let address = "John Doe\nStreetname 1\n 1234AA Village";
  let firstname = address.split(' ')[0]; 
  return firstname;
}

function customerText(){
   let text = "Dear "+firstName()+", how is life?";
   alert(text);
}

// call your function
customerText();
```

**OR** pass firstname as parameter to the second function

```js
function firstName(){
  let address = "John Doe\nStreetname 1\n 1234AA Village";
  let firstname = address.split(' ')[0]; 
  customerText(firstname);
}

function customerText(nameParameter){
   let text = "Dear "+nameParameter+", how is life?";
   alert(text);
}

// call your function
firstName();
```

Comment: It seems like the OP's `firstName()` function may be used for multiple things ,not just for the customer text, so it shouldn't automatically call `customerText()`.

Comment: FirstName() is the function that needs to be called in more other functions. In the first  example you only call customerText() so I don't understand how script also runs firstName()?

Answer (score -1):

Here is the modified code: I hope this will help you.

```js
function firstName() {
    let address = "John Doe\nStreetname 1\n 1234AA Village";
    let firstname = address.split(' ')[0];
    customerText(firstname);
}

function customerText(fname) {
    let text = "Dear " + fname + ", how is life?";
    alert(text);
}

firstName();
```